# linux router, 2x NIC, HA with interface bonding, two ethernet switches

Tags: linux, networking, centos7, high-availability, bonding

I have two NIC server (eth0, eth1) that I use as router. I have two switches working in stack.

Is it a good idea / possible to create on them two bond lacp interfaces ( bond0, bond1 ).

And use bond0 and bond1 as I now use eth0 (as external interface) and eth1 (as internal interface).

Both are 10Gb interfaces.
I use centos7 .
My goal is to create router more that will still work in case one of switches stop working.

---

I find comment by davidgo to be most helpfull.
vlan interfaces on single bond0 should be enough to solve my problem of single switch malfunction.

Comment: bonding afaik requires 2 devices for failover, so add an ethnercard with 2 ports and then,  yes imho

Comment: What you are proposing makes no sense. You are just adding more complexity but not getting anything in return. If your switches are clan capable, why not put eth0 and eth1 into a single bond interface and use vlans on top of the bond interfaces to convert the switch into something that resembles multiple ports on the router?

Comment: On your Linux box you can then do routing between bond0.x devices where each x is a different vlan.